# $('#iframe').height is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the iFrame to take up 80% height and advertisement to have the remaining 20%.

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe id="iframe" src="xxxxxx" style="border:0; width:100%;"></iframe>  
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
    <!-- Text/image -->
    <ins class="adsbygoogle"
         style="display:block"
         data-ad-client="xxxxxx"
         data-ad-slot="xxxxxx"
         data-ad-format="auto"></ins>
    <script>
    (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
    </script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('#iframe').height('80%');
    });     

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#iframe').height('80%');
    });        
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Screenshot

[image]

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: `html, body {
  height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;
}`

Comment: and `height:80%` in iframe's style should work - no need for jQuery's `height()`

Comment: @van_folmert Ya, there is no point of using js/jq here

Comment: @van_folmert doesn't work. Looks the same. Also using style will not fix it if iFrame is resized, hence jQuery !

Answer (score 4):

Normally the height of elements depend on the height of the content inside or the height of a parent element when using percentages.

For example when you're setting the height of the iframe to 80%, it means 80% of the parent height. The parent to the iframe is the body and html so for it to take up 80% of the screen you'd need to make the html and body height 100%

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Play around with: http://codepen.io/aihowes/pen/GqEXQO to see if you get an understanding.

Comment: AFAIK, you should add `margin: 0; padding: 0;` to make it less browser dependant